# What 0 returned by InputStream.read(byte[]) means? How to handle this?

Tags: java, io, inputstream

What 0 (number of bytes read) returned by `InputStream.read(byte[])` and `InputStream.read(byte[], int, int)` means? How to handle this situation?

To be clear, I mean `read(byte[] b)` or `read(byte[] b, int off, int len)` methods which return number of bytes read.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The only situation in which a `InputStream` may return `0` from a call to [`read(byte[])`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) is when the `byte[]` passed in has a length of 0:

```
 byte[] buf = new byte[0];
 int read = in.read(buf); // read will contain 0
```

As specified by this part of the JavaDoc:

> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned

My guess: you used [`available()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) to see how big the buffer should be and it returned `0`. Note that this is a misuse of `available()`. The JavaDoc explicitly states that:

> It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

Comment: I agree:

>This method blocks until input data is available, end of file is detected, or an exception is thrown.

>If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte.
>If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the implementation of javax.sound.AudioInputStream#read(byte[] b, int off, int len) ... yuck. They completely violated the standard java.io.InputStream semantics and return a read size of 0 if you request fewer than a whole frame of data.

So unfortunately; the common advice (and api spec) should preclude having to deal with return of zero when len > 0 but even for JDK provided classes you can't universally rely on this to be true for InputStreams of arbitrary types.

Again, yuck.

Comment: InputStream from UrlConnection.getInputStream() seems also violated the standard java.io.InputStream semantics and return a read size of 0 when handling large file. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: ^ Yes, thats confirmed, I came to this question when searching for the same exact problem of UrlConnection.getInputStream read returning a zero 0

Answer (score 3):

According to Java API Doc:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])

It only can happen if the byte[] you passed has zero items (new byte[0]).

In other situations it must return at least one byte. Or -1 if EOF reached. Or an exception.

**Of course:** it depends of the actual implementation of the InputStream you are using!!! (it could be a wrong one)

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same behavior (reading 0 bytes) when I build a swing console output window and made a reader-thread for stdout and stderr via the following code:

```
                this.pi = new PipedInputStream();
                po = new PipedOutputStream((PipedInputStream)pi);
                System.setOut(new PrintStream(po, true));
```

When the 'main' swing application exits, and my console window is still open I read 0 from this.pi.read().
The read data was put on the console window resulting in a race condition some how, just ignoring the result and not updating the console window solved the issue.