# Java process hanging on IOUtils. Suspected deadlock

Tags: deadlock, java, apache-commons-io

I have a java process that is hanging in a call to `IOUtils.toString` with the following code:

```
String html = "";
try {
    html = IOUtils.toString(someUrl.openStream(), "utf-8"); // process hangs on this line
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

It can't reproduce this reliably. It's part of a web crawler and so executes this line thousands of times successfully but ultimately causes the process to hang here after a few days.

Output from [jstack](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tooldescr-136044.html#gblfh):

```
2013-09-25 09:09:36
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (20.0-b12 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2b1c001000 nid=0x225a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Thread-0" prio=10 tid=0x00007f2b34122000 nid=0x187b runnable [0x00007f2b30970000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:146)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
        - locked <0x00000000e3d2d160> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAheadBlocking(ChunkedInputStream.java:552)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.readAhead(ChunkedInputStream.java:609)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:696)
        - locked <0x00000000e3d30558> (a sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:2582)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:282)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:324)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:176)
        - locked <0x00000000e3d317d0> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1364)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1340)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:1315)
        at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(IOUtils.java:525)
```

I can't see any way to set a timeout on the toString method. Any suggestions? Is this a bug in Apache commons? Or in my OpenJDK perhaps?

Comment: May be 'someUrl' shared between threads?

Comment: ioutils is open source.  Attach a debugger, pause the vm and see where it is stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to try simply using guava IO instead since it was already in my classpath anyway:

```
String html = "";
try {
    InputSupplier<? extends InputStream> supplier = Resources
            .newInputStreamSupplier(metaUrl);
    html = CharStreams.toString(CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(supplier,
            Charsets.UTF_8));
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

It generally takes a few days to crash so if I don't update this answer in a few days, assume this worked!

Update : 7 days so far without hanging... :)

Comment: thanks for posting the solution! I got this in 2017 so I wonder why this is still not fixed..

Answer (score 4):

Your call to toString() is ultimately forwarded to [copyLarge()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#line.1910). Here you can see that reading from the stream is continued until an end of file (EOF) marker is detected by InputStream.read(). According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319395/what-0-returned-by-inputstream-read-means-how-to-handle-this) read() can read 0 bytes, i.e., if the URLConnection your reading from does not return an EOF marker the method keeps probably reading 0 bytes forever.

Maybe you can track down which URL causes the problem?

Anyways, to realize a timeout you could start each reading in a separate thread and kill that thread after a certain time elapsed.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. I'm not that fussed about which url caused it, but it may help me design a reproducible test. I'm trying guava as an alternative because it's simple, but if that fails, then I think running it in a separate thread may be my only option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Maybe it gets solved by using guava but in my opinion the root of the problem is that the socket has no soTimeout configured.

try

`socket.setSoTimeout(10000)`

to throw a SocketTimeoutException when there is no EOF coming after 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Java native method:

> InputStream in = new URL(url).openStream();

Guava method:

> InputSupplier supplier =
>   Resources.newInputStreamSupplier(new URL(url)); 
>   InputStream in = supplier.getInput();

Both of them will throw Connection timed out Exception. Because guave is also use URL.openStream()

But some site is so slow that I can read a little data from it every time, and so many many times still not reach end. And I also see it is hang there by Jstack.

Like this(maybe only slow at my host): [a txt file address](http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1503584/000093041315003418/0000930413-15-003418.txt)