# application frezes IOUtils.toString()

Tags: java, socrata

I have an application that I need to read some open data from a (Socrata) dataset using their API. Since there are many records on that dataset, I am looping it through using offsets inside a while

```
//initialize variables
//...
do{
    System.out.println("1");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(url+offset).openStream()));
    String reply=IOUtils.toString( in );
    //read the page to a String and convert to JSON
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(reply);
    //close connection
    in.close();
    JSONArray results=obj.getJSONArray("results");
            //do something here 
    offset+=100;
}while(results.length()!=0&&offset<=endOffset);
```

This seems to be working fine for a few iterations(roughly 20-50), but then for no reason and not always on the same offset, it just hangs after the

```
String reply=IOUtils.toString( in );
```

for ever.
I tried to use guava as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19002648/3963249) suggested with no difference
and this

```
String reply = CharStreams.toString( new InputStreamReader( new URL(runHost+offset).openStream(), "UTF-8" ) );
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4185715/3963249) which seems to be doing a better job but again hanged after around 70 iterations.

Is there at least a way to stop the loop if there is a long delay and continue with the rest of the program?( as a worst case scenario)
**EDIT**
regarding @Mad Matts commend, result is the JSONArray converted from the JSONObject I get from the API.(code updated)
I use `&&` at the condition since I need the loop to repeat if the array is not empty(`results.length()!=0`) and the offset is smaller than the `endOffset`. That last part I used it just to avoid the hanging of the procedure. I can at least run it for 10 offsets at a time, get my results and run it again for the next 10 offsets and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java process hanging on IOUtils. Suspected deadlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000509/java-process-hanging-on-ioutils-suspected-deadlock)

Comment: @YMomb yes, I have seen that post, and i mention it on my question that i tried that solution with no luck

Comment: From which array is your `results.length()` coming from? sure your condition should be `&&` ?

Comment: @MadMatts see updated question & code