# What is difference between "while (-1 != (len = in.read(b)))" and "while ((len = in.read(b)) > 0)" in Java IO?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, java-io

I have this (working) code:

```
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
int len;
while (-1 != (len = in.read(b))) {
    fos.write(b, 0, len);
}
fos.flush();
```

But if I change the `while (-1 != (len = in.read(b)))` to `while ((len = in.read(b)) > 0)`, the stream cannot finish. Why is this?

Comment: Well, the condition isn't exactly the same `i > 0` and `i != -1`, in this case, the difference is not much execpt that it is supposed to return `-1` at the end, but `i > 0` could stop at `0` too.

Comment: So ... I have tested this with a `ByteArrayInputStream` to create a [mcve] and both solution works (as expected). Can you provide a [mcve] without using your url connection ?

Comment: For me both the program working as expected and ending execution. Can you elaborate more on same

Comment: It's a not-thinking-problem rather than a programming problem.

Answer (score 1):

On first sight, these two conditions may seem very different. Let's rearrange them so that `(len = in.read(b))` is always on the left:

```
(len = in.read(b)) != -1

(len = in.read(b)) > 0
```

The expression `(len = in.read(b))` evaluates to just `in.read(b)`. Therefore, the only difference between the two conditions is that the first checks if `read` does not return -1, while the second checks if `read` returns a value greater than 0.

Let's look at [what `read` can return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])):

> **Returns:**
>
> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

This means that `read` does not return anything less than -1, which in turn means that the two conditions in question will only evaluate to different values if `read` returns 0. But look, `read` only returns 0 when no byte is read, and the only time that no byte is read is when you pass in an array of length 0:

> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned;
>   otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte
>   is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value
>   -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.

Your array has a constant length of `1024`, so in this particular case, the two conditions will produce identical results.

Comment: I completely agree with this (well, who can disagree the documentation) but this doesn't answer the question. "_if I change the `while (-1 != (len = in.read(b)))` to `while ((len = in.read(b)) > 0)`, the stream cannot finish. Why is this?_". Strangely, this let us assume the stream never return `-1` but `0` even with this array of size 1024.

Comment: @AxelH I would say that some other parts of OP's code is causing the problem.

Comment: Clearly, but it seems I am the only one waiting for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read()) for the method `InputSteam.read(byte[] b)`:

> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and **0 is returned**;
>   otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte
>   is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value
>   **-1 is returned**; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.

So, basically, when you use `while ((len = in.read(b)) > 0)` you are exiting the loop if `read()` return 0 (meaning that the length of the last read byte is 0), even though the end of stream has not been reached and, thus, there is still data to be read (the stream is not finished).

Answer (score 0):

You are entirely changing condition rule. The first statement check value exactly for not matching -1, so your new condition should met the requirements that value is in range of (-infinity,-1) and (-1, infinity)

```
(-1 != (len = in.read(b))) // read until reach end of stream
(len = in.read(b)) > 0) // read until data are present but this is wrong
```

Change it to:

```
(len = in.read(b)) >= 0)
```

I am not sure why to change this condition anyway. As docs say:

> returns the number of bytes read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached.

Situation described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319395/what-0-returned-by-inputstream-read-means-how-to-handle-this)

Comment: It'd be interesting to specify when a result of `0` could occur.  The [`InputStream doc`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read-byte:A-) says "If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned; otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value -1 is returned; **otherwise, at least one byte is read** and stored into b."  The only time it seems to allow a `0` result is when the buffer passed in has zero length (not the case here)